# Is there a way for a thread to know it has been "interleaved"?

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

In Java, is there a way for a thread to know it has been "interleaved"?

I would like to send a certain update to my clients (who are handled by individual threads) after their thread has been interleaved by another thread.
In case my use of the term "interleaved" is incorrect, I'm referring to the process where the processor stops running one thread and moves to another one.
So when the processor eventually returns to my thread, I would like a certain update to be sent to my client via the thread.

Comment: 'Interleaving', as you call it, is the normal case,not an exceptional case. You will be sending one of those updates every few milliseconds. I cannot believe that you really have such a requirement. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I actually do want to send an update every few milliseconds. Basically, changes done by the client himself aren't all that important. It's the changes that are done by the OTHER users that interest the client (in this case). So whenever I return to the client's thread, I would like to update him/her (even though this is very frequent.)...

Comment: What changes? It sounds like what you really need is a listener system.

Comment: basically, I'm creating a whiteboard that will be modified concurrently by multiple threads. So, sending an update every time an action is performed will be expensive, but sending one once per "interleave" would probably be ideal!

Comment: It would most certainly not be ideal. Interleaving could happen orders of magnitude more often than actual changes to your object. You don't need this. Use a listener, or maybe poll for changes.

Comment: hmmm. that's a good point. Now I'm thinking of having an atomic variable representing the amount of changes actually done, and sending the update whenever a certain threshold has been exceeded. Out of curiosity, could you clarify what you meant by using the listener system? Also, in regards to my original question, IS there a way to know whether or not a thread has been interleaved? Thank you for your help and advice!

Comment: Surely you are are aware of the Listener pattern? Java AWT and Swing are full of them. There is no way to detect that a thread has been 'interleaved' in Java.

Comment: I'm familiar, thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is no simple way to detect that a thread has been interleaved.
Instead, I decided to use an atomic integer to track the amount of updates that were executed by all threads.
I then changed the code within my threads to monitor the amount of changes that had been done (since last notifying the client) and, once a certain threshold had been exceeded, I updated the client.